# Functionally add new column based on division of two others

Tags: r

**Background**

Sorry if this is a repeat, I couldn't find an exact match to this question.
So as part of a larger function, I'm trying to add a new column in a data.frame which is basically the division of two variables within that data.frame.

For example:

```
data(iris)

iris_test <- function(dataset, var1, var2) {
  data <- dataset
  data$length_width <- data$var1/data$var2
  return(data)
}
```

If i then utilize this function

```
iris <- iris_test(iris, 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')
```

I would hopefully generate a new column with `data$length_width`, however the code is breaking.

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "length_width", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 150
```

I suspect you could do something fancy with paste() or formula() but really I want to understand what is happening and wy.

Comment: you can not use character values for the dollar notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use character variables for the dollar notation. Try this:

```
data(iris)

iris_test <- function(dataset, var1, var2) {
  data <- dataset
  data$length_width <- data[[var1]]/data[[var2]]
  return(data)
}
```